# how to hide notification for specific activity?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm getting notification from fcm when app is in foreground or background.
I don't want to show the notification When app in a specific activity how to disable notification when app is in specific activity.

I'm using datapaylod to for notification

Comment: kill service before starting the activity and restart it when leaving the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
  private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Intent notificationIntent = null;
    notificationIntent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GCMNotificationIntentService.this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) GCMNotificationIntentService.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Resources res = GCMNotificationIntentService.this.getResources();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(GCMNotificationIntentService.this);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo_small_trans)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_logo_color))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.app_logo))
            .setTicker(msg)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Propreka")
            .setLights(0xffff0000, 100, 2000)
            .setPriority(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentText(msg);

    Notification n = builder.getNotification();

    n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    nm.notify(0, n);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check current top activity by:

```
public static Activity getActivity() {
Class activityThreadClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
Object activityThread = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentActivityThread").invoke(null);
Field activitiesField = activityThreadClass.getDeclaredField("mActivities");
activitiesField.setAccessible(true);

Map<Object, Object> activities = (Map<Object, Object>) activitiesField.get(activityThread);
if (activities == null)
    return null;

for (Object activityRecord : activities.values()) {
    Class activityRecordClass = activityRecord.getClass();
    Field pausedField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("paused");
    pausedField.setAccessible(true);
    if (!pausedField.getBoolean(activityRecord)) {
        Field activityField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("activity");
        activityField.setAccessible(true);
        Activity activity = (Activity) activityField.get(activityRecord);
        return activity;
    }
}

return null;
}
```

you can check if top activity is the activity in which you don't want to show notification and then return the call from service.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know which (if any) activity is in foreground at the moment. And depending on the class type, want to limit the showing of notifications.

You need to maintain this yourself. Easiest way is to write a new class and have public static functions in it to mark activity as active / inactive

```
public static Activity mCurrentActivity = null;

public static void SetActivity(Activtiy activity) { mCurrentActivity = activity };

public static void ClearActivity(Activtiy activity) 
{ 
    if (mCurrentActivity.equals(activity))
         mCurrentActivity = null;
}

public static Activity GetCurrentActivity() { return mCurrentActivity; }
```

Once you have such an infra, you can call the SetActivity and ClearActivity functions in all of your onResume and onPause overrides respectively.

Finally, in your notification builder class, you will get the instance of current activity and compare the .class to check if your desired activity is the one in focus. If the Current activity returns null, it means your app is not in foreground.

There are better, more efficient and cleaner way to do this. E.g. Dependency Injection with Daggr.