# How to control whether to display notification or not based on the screen that is being displayed in android studio?

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-jetpack-compose, message

I am making a chat application and I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications. Everything is working fine but I do not want to display notification if the app is already in chat screen. I am using jetpack compose for UI and have single-activity architecture.

So in my chat screen, I don't want to display the notification. However, if the user is at other screens, I want to display the notification.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71627864/how-can-i-disable-receiving-notification-in-a-specific-activity-in-kotlin), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563994/how-to-hide-notification-for-specific-activity) out

Comment: well in 1, its stating to handle whether to show the notification or not in FirebaseMessaggingService... The problem is I do not know the state of UI inside the service and I was hoping for a way to know the state of the UI inside the service..

In 2.. its stating to detect the top of the activity stack to know the current top activity. As I stated I have a single-activity architecture and this method doesn't help.

Comment: What you can do is create a static variable in your activity that you toggle based on the Fragment that you're on. in your receiver you can query this variable and display the Notification accordingly. Just make sure that in the onPause/onDestroy/onResume the variable is toggled correctly as well.

Comment: I did make it work using static variables. I thought maybe there are better ways or standard practices to achieve so without static variables.
Some ideas I am having are as 1) binding my destination to the service and communicate between service and UI through binders. But I haven't yet found a single implementation with this idea and am having mixed feelings about it. 2) Using ordered broadcasts.. https://medium.com/@deividi/a-good-way-to-handle-incoming-notifications-in-android-dc64c29041a5. But many deprecated methods. So I hope to get some standard practices used in production apps.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two possible solutions

1. Declare boolean in Activity or SharedPreference and toggle value according to lifecycle event's.
2. Once you receive firebase notification send broadcast and listen in activity. Inside activity identify top most visible screen using `navController` like below and decide wheather to show notification or not.

`val visibleScreenRoute = parentNavController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route?.split(Constants.KEY_QUESTION_MARK)?.getOrNull(0)`

Hope this will help you to solve the issue.

Comment: Use activity to show notification?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case as you.

First, you need to create a custom notification and control push notifications manually.

Second, you have a module which checks whether activity is displaying or not.

Finally, when you receive notification data from firebase, using above module to decide display notification or not.

Check this document for more details : [Build Notification](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification)

Comment: I am displaying notifications manually. I am having problems creating the module you described. Could you please guide me a bit more for creating this module?

Comment: @DikenMhrz The simplest way, you create singleton class with a boolean variable name "isActivityForeground" and can set or get it. And in your activity, set true in onResume and false in onPause. Then, use it in your service.

Comment: I am trying hard to not use singleton classes and static variables. Do you have another way of achieving this? If not I would have to fallback to these methods.

Comment: @DikenMhrz You can use send data to service via intent in activity. If service is running, just handle logic in onStartCommand

Comment: If I start the service myself , won't it disrupt the normal FirebaseMessagingService lifecycle?
The service will be in started state and I have no idea whether I should stop it or leave it be.

Comment: @DikenMhrz If my answer is correct, please mark it as an answer. If not, talk to me about how to correct it. Because my solution resolves your problem.

Comment: @DikenMhrz yes, if your service is running, start service only receive data, not disrupt it

Comment: But if the service is not running, wouldn't I be starting the service and would be interfering with the FirebaseMessagingService lifecycle?